# Indoor swimming in Tel Aviv. Israel?

Tags: israel, swimming

Often hotels with swimming pools will let non-guests purchase a pass to their pool but it can be pricey.  Sometimes there are municipal swimming pools that do not make it to the guide books but which accept walk-in guests for a modest fee.  I am seeking info on the indoor swimming options in the Tel Aviv area, Israel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://www.secrettelaviv.com/magazine/blog/useful-info/swimming-pools-in-tel-aviv/) page has a list of swimming pools in Tel Aviv, both in and outdoor. It also has links to their sites, and prices.

The pools that don't have a price on the page, also don't have a price on their site.

The pools that do have a price listed:

- [Jimmy’s Pool](http://www.gymi.co.il/) – Dizengoff Centre Top Floor,  03-6201130 : 70 NIS.
- [Tel Aviv University](http://www.sports-center.co.il/?CategoryID=1117) – Haim Levanon 64, 074-710-0200 : 72-85 NIS.
- [Country Dekel](http://www.countrydekel.co.il/) – Kosovski st. 69, 03-5465911 : 85-100 NIS.